# No Network, my HTC desire not identifying network operator

Tags: htc-desire, airplane-mode

There is no network in my HTC desire, because airplane mode is switching turned on and off continuously. I have tried with factory reset, it is still in same state.

Comment: This sounds like a defective SIM card, or a defective device, can you test with a different SIM?

Answer (score 0):

Power off completely. Remove sim card. Check if the problem recurs. If it does not replace sim card.